# Does scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' in app-routing work for pages containing scrollable paginated data that are lazy loaded in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, scroll-position

I have a page with paginated data in a column on left and a map on right (ex. Airbnb)
When I click on the next page at the bottom of the column, I fetch the page data which returns a list of items (ex. members), but my scrollable column, which is a bootstrap column, doesn't scroll to the top, it stays at the bottom and just updates the new list of data items.

FYI - I used scrollpositionrestoration in my app-routing file like this, but it doesn't scroll the scrollable paginated list, within the column, in the page.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'})
```

The page where the paginated list isn't scrolling to the top is contained in it's own module (ex. members.module.ts) with it's own routing file (ex. members-routing.module.tx) and it's being lazy loaded like this.

in app-routing.ts

```
{
  path: 'members',
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  loadChildren: () => import('./members/members.module')
    .then(mod => mod.MembersModule)
},
```

and in the member-routing.module.ts file I have this

```js
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: MembersComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: MemberDetailsComponent,
    resolve: {
      user: MemberDetailResolver
    },
    data: {
      breadcrumb: {
        alias: 'memberDetails'
      }
    }
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MembersRoutingModule {}
```

**QUESTION** - Do I need to do some other type of importing or exporting with 'scrollPositionRestoration' to get this to work or does this not work on scrollable column data?

My current solution is to get the elementRef in the .ts file and then after I've fetched the data, scroll to the top. But this doesn't seem like a good Angular 9+ solution?

ex.

```js
// above in the .ts file get col that contains the paginated data
@ViewChild('scrollableContentCol', {
  static: true
}) scrollableContentCol: ElementRef;

// gets the member data
this.membersService.getMembers()
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.totalCount = response.count;
    this.scrollableContentCol.nativeElement.scrollTo(0, 0); // scroll the col with paginated data back to top
    this.members = response.data as IUser[];
    // do other stuff
  });
```